# Swift unwrap optional init inside convenience init

Tags: swift, option-type, init

Is it possible to unwrap optional init somehow inside convenience init?

```
convenience init(...) {
   self.init?(...) ?? self.init()
}
```

Actually, I'm trying to make convenience init for `UIColor`:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(for item: ItemType) {
       self.init(named: item.rawValue) ?? self.init() // something like this
       //self.init(named: item.rawValue)! // works
    }
}
```

Comment: For a UIColor, what would `self.init()` mean?

Comment: @matt initialize default color. It can be different, like self.init(white: 1, alpha: 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have such an unwrapping, because it is forbidden to delegate a non-failable initializer to a failable initializer.  This is the consequence of the [following language reference principle](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html):

> In either case, if you delegate to another initializer that causes initialization to fail, the entire initialization process fails immediately, and no further initialization code is executed.

Answer (score 5):

Initializers are highly restricted in how they can speak. But factory methods are not! This compiles (and works):

```
extension UIColor {
    static func create(for item: ItemType) -> UIColor {
        UIColor(named: item.rawValue) ?? UIColor()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```swift
convenience init(for item: ItemType) {
    if let value = UIColor(named: item.rawValue) {
        self = value
    } else {
        self.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `self = value` will give a compiler error: *"Cannot assign to value: 'self' is immutable"*.