# optional convenience init with multiple attempts to initialise

Tags: swift, initialization, uiimage

I have a factory method on `UIImage` that looks in multiple bundles for the image as the projects I'm working on are sometimes broken up.

`Key` is an enum for type safety around various properties.

```
public extension UIImage {
    static func with(_ key: Key, in bundle: Bundle? = nil) -> UIImage? {
        if let image = UIImage(key, in: bundle) { return image }
        if let image = UIImage(key, in: .main) { return image }
        if let image = UIImage(key, in: Bundle(for: BrandManager.self)) { return image }
        print("Failed to find \(key.rawValue) in any bundle")
        return nil
    }
    
    convenience init?(_ key: Key, in bundle: Bundle? = nil) {
        self.init(named: key.rawValue, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
    }
}
```

This is fine, but obviously it means I need to add `.with` every time i.e. `UIImage.with(.key)` when I'd prefer to use the `convenience init` directly to drop `with`

Looking here [Swift unwrap optional init inside convenience init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70566273/swift-unwrap-optional-init-inside-convenience-init)

this isn't possible with `convenience init`... but is there another a way to get the syntax and look in multiple bundles? I can bury it inside `UIImageView` but I'm looking for it directly on `UIImage`

Thanks

Comment: I don’t understand what the problem is to use `with` so it’s hard to know what you want instead?

Comment: I agree with @JoakimDanielson Nothing wrong with your `.with` function

Comment: I want to drop it, so the external syntax is `UIImage(.key)`

Comment: `UIImage(with: .key)` would also be acceptable

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer by @JeremyP

I tried `url(forResource...` but for some reason it always came back as nil... It was a good idea though...

Here's what I have, it feels pretty ugly to build the image twice.. but as I said the other one always came back with `nil` for the url. I tried adding the extension but it didn't help.

```
    convenience init?(_ key: Key, in bundle: Bundle? = nil) {
        
        var correctBundle: Bundle?
        let bundles = [bundle,
                       .main,
                       Bundle(for: BrandManager.self)].compactMap { $0 }
        
        for b in bundles {
            guard UIImage(named: key.rawValue, in: b, compatibleWith: nil) != nil else { continue }
            // guard b.url(forResource: key.rawValue, withExtension: nil) != nil else { continue }
            correctBundle = b
            break
        }

        self.init(named: name, in: correctBundle, compatibleWith: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I just realised that... these are not added to the project as files, which is why the url is nil. the asset catalogue is opaque. I didn't know I can create real init's on extensions.. let me search for that.. I could always sublass UIImage, but I'd rather not if there's another way

Comment: There's really no clean way I can see to make this a pure `init` instead of a `convenience init`

Comment: Well then maybe your original factory method was cleaner! :)

Comment: haha dammit :( I want my fancy syntax. I miss `self = UIImage....`

Answer (score 0):

If you would accept `UIImage[.key]` as a plausible calling syntax, you could express your factory method as a `static subscript`.

Comment: That is pretty swish, I'll look to adopt it. It was more because I have `UIImageView(.key)` and wanted to standardise `UIImage` so consumers of my design system would have less to think about. this is still less words though, which is always desirable. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Having said in the comments that I see nothing wrong with the `with` function, you can dispense with it.

Instead of trying to initialise the image directly, you can first search for it in all the bundles by looking for the path name or URL using e.g. [Bundle.url(forResource:withExtension:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1411540-url) and then load the image from the first bundle where that returns non `nil` (or even use the URL to initialise the image).